# How to destructure object from custom hook to getCurrentPosition for user's location

Tags: reactjs, object, react-hooks, geolocation, destructuring

I have created a simple custom react hook to get users location.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useGeoLocation = async () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({
        loaded: false,
        accuracy: '',
        coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
        error: null
    });
    // console.log(location)

    const onSuccess = (location) => {
        setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            accuracy: location.accuracy,
            coordinates: {
                lat: location.coords.latitude,
                lng: location.coords.longitude,
            },
        });
    };

    const onError = (error) => {
        setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            error: {
                code: error.code,
                message: error.message,
            },
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
            onError({
                code: 0,
                message: "Geolocation not supported",
            });
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }, []);

    return location;
};

export default useGeoLocation;
```

However when I try to destructure location by calling the hook in my functional component. It is returning undefined.

Somewhere in my functional component

```
const { location } = useGeoLocation()
console.log(location)
```

I have tried to console log the whole query with

```
const location = useGeoLocation()
console.log(location)
```

However I am getting a promise that is fullfilled after sometime and my location object is present inside the result but I am not able to get this value out.

[image: screenshot of the console]

I am noob and expecting help from experts.

Answer (score 2):

Please stop adding `async` everywhere. It should be used only if you want to use `await`. `async` makes your function return a promise

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useGeoLocation = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState({
        loaded: false,
        accuracy: '',
        coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
        error: null
    });
    // console.log(location)

    const onSuccess = (location) => {
        setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            accuracy: location.accuracy,
            coordinates: {
                lat: location.coords.latitude,
                lng: location.coords.longitude,
            },
        });
    };

    const onError = (error) => {
        setLocation({
            loaded: true,
            error: {
                code: error.code,
                message: error.message,
            },
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
            onError({
                code: 0,
                message: "Geolocation not supported",
            });
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }, []);

    return location;
};

export default useGeoLocation;
```

Usage

```
const location = useGeoLocation()
console.log(location)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hustling with code initially when I put async but later forgot to remove when useGetLocation was working internally.